# How can I keep one hacked website on my server from compromising the other websites?

Tags: nginx, permissions, hacking, www-data

I'm a teaching assistant in software security and running a server that is vulnerable by design.

It's an nginx server, and it has 40 ports open. Each port serves a web application, and all the web applications are very vulnerable to hacking. If one web application is compromised, the attacker will gain the privileges of the www-data user, and the attacker will then be able to compromise the other 39 web applications. Is there any way I can keep this from happening? I don't want the attacker to gain access rights *beyond* the single hacked web application.

Hardware limitations on the server makes Docker unfeasible, let alone VMs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: My scenario is very different. I edited the question.

Comment: You can fairly easily isolate the applications and application data by having each application run under its own UID and then normal file-system permissions may already be sufficient to prevent one application from modifying the data of the others.

Comment: @HBruijn this is essentially the correct answer.

Comment: @HBruijn How should the questioner do that? Apache offers [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html), but that's only for CGI and SSI programs.

Comment: For static content there is no issue, in nginx dynamic content such as PHP scripts get handled by php-fpm that allow an admin to start workers with different uid/gid/chroot/environment, listening on different ports and using different php.ini filed @AndrewSchulman

Comment: Anything that will run 40 web applications at the same time will run Docker.

Comment: Somewhat concerning this question is not only relevant in education but also to many web hosting companies.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The server has other roles besides nginx web hosting. I have a few hundred MBs of RAM to spare. Would that suffice to host 40 docker containers?

Answer (score 3):

> If one web application is compromised, the attacker will gain the privileges of the www-data user, and the attacker will then be able to compromise the other 39 web applications. Is there any way I can keep this from happening?

Yes.  Don't do that.  There's absolutely no reason to run unrelated applications as a single user.  There's over 65,000 available user IDs on a typical Unix-like system, and you should take advantage of them.  How to do that is dependent on the specific application and the technologies it uses, which would be best asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a unique situation for apps, but I'd ask this of the developers: if the app is a PHP app, why can't they use `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` to get the current port for the current app, and cordon off data accordingly? This can be added as a check at the top of a PHP program, and if something untoward is observed, just `exit();` or do something that clearly prohibits the undesirable behaviour. How precisely to do this depends on the application.

Comment: While this might work it's far from the best way to do it.